# Apache fails to start a Django App (mod_wsgi) on openSUSE 12.3

Tags: django, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

Apache fails to start a Django WEB Application using mod_wsgi and I am not able to figure out why.

The error in starting of apache is this

```
linux-ua6r:/etc/apache2/vhosts.d # /etc/init.d/apache2 start
redirecting to systemctl  start apache2
Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -n' for details.
linux-ua6r:/etc/apache2/vhosts.d # systemctl status apache2.service
apache2.service - apache
          Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled)
          Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue, 2013-05-28 04:13:12 PDT; 15s ago
         Process: 8953 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/httpd2 -D SYSTEMD -k stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 8991 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/start_apache2 -D SYSTEMD -k start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        Main PID: 8918 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/apache2.service

May 28 04:13:12 linux-ua6r.site systemd[1]: Failed to start apache.
May 28 04:13:12 linux-ua6r.site systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state
```

If i remove my vhosts.conf file though, it starts without this error . . . The vhosts conf file itself has the following contents

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin j@j.com
        ServerName www.Services.pes.com
        ErrorLog server-logs/pes_error_log
        CustomLog server-logs/pes_access_log common

        WSGIScriptAlias /pes "/root/pweb/django.wsgi"

        <Directory "/root/pweb/">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be the following line line(Either comment it out, or make sure mod_wsgi is loaded and working or use alias directive)

```
WSGIScriptAlias /pes "/root/pweb/django.wsgi"
```

To use the alias directive use following, but note, you probably want get mod_wsgi to work.

```
Alias /pes "/root/pweb/django.wsgi"
```

To see if mod_wsgi is loaded, try this and look for the module name:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -M
```

Background:
You also want verify that the target directory/file exist and its health
    ll /root/pweb/django.wsgi

Comment: Using an Alias directive is not equivalent to using WSGIScriptAlias and will not yield the same result. It may well be that mod_wsgi module isn't enabled for the Apache installation, but getting rid of WSGIScriptAlias is not the solution.

Comment: What am I supposed to be looking at. I wrote that document you refer to. The Alias directive is not equivalent if all you are going to do is change WSGIScriptAlias to Alias. If you are going to use Alias, you must also use SetHandler or the AddHandler directive to map .wsgi to mod_wsgi and enable ExecCGI for the directory. Your solution doesn't say anything about that so in itself is not equivalent. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive